# MagicalRecord fetch two entities with row and sections and sort Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

[image]

i have two objects GroupExercise <---->> Exercise, And Need do fetch request for tableView with sections (header GroupExercise.name) and rows (Exercise.name)
how i can fetch two entities with Magical Record Or Core Data

Exercise object

```
    @interface Exercise : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * timeRelax;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uid;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uidGroup;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) GroupExercise *groupEdge;
```

GroupExerciseObject

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tagColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *exerciseEdge;
```

save objects with code

```
- (void)parseAndSaveJson:(id)json withCompleteBlock:(void (^)())completeBlock {

NSMutableArray *groupsArray = (NSMutableArray *) json;

NSLog(@"%@", json);

if (groupsArray != nil) {

    NSArray *allEntities = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_defaultManagedObjectModel].entities;

    [allEntities enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSEntityDescription *entityDescription, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [NSClassFromString([entityDescription managedObjectClassName]) MR_truncateAll];
    }];

    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {


        for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < [groupsArray count]; groupIndex++) {


            GroupExercise *localGroup = [GroupExercise MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

            localGroup.name = groupsArray[groupIndex][LOCAL_GROUPS_NAME];

            localGroup.tagColor = groupsArray[groupIndex][LOCAL_GROUPS_TAG_COLOR];

            localGroup.uid = @([groupsArray[groupIndex][LOCAL_GROUPS_ID_GROUP] intValue]);


            NSMutableArray *exerciseArray = (NSMutableArray *) groupsArray[groupIndex][LOCAL_GROUPS_EXERCISES];

            NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

            for (int exerciseIndex = 0; exerciseIndex < [exerciseArray count]; exerciseIndex++) {

                Exercise *exercise = [Exercise MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];

                exercise.name = exerciseArray[exerciseIndex][EXERCISE_NAME];
                exercise.uid = @([exerciseArray[exerciseIndex][LOCAL_EXERCISE_ID_EXERCISE] intValue]);
                exercise.uidGroup = @([groupsArray[groupIndex][LOCAL_GROUPS_ID_GROUP] intValue]);
                exercise.groupEdge = localGroup;

                [set addObject:exercise];
            }

            [localGroup addExerciseEdge:set];
        }

    }                 completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {

        completeBlock();

    }];
}
}
```

and use FRC

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

_fetchedResultsController = [Exercise MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"groupEdge" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"uid" ascending:true];


_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

how i can sort sections with groupEdge.name ?

Comment: Does the group change while its displayed? Do you really need to fetch both, or just the exercises?

Answer (score 0):

i solved with code

`_fetchedResultsController = [Exercise MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"groupEdge" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"uidGroup,uid" ascending:true];`